# Bootstrap carousel animate top to bottom instead of left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any option in bootstrap carousel to animate it to top to bottom and bottom to top, instead of right to left and left to right.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fwuq/403/)**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h1>Example headline.</h1>

                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h1>Another example headline.</h1>

                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>

                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589816/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-vertical-sliding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get change the direction of carousel using this code (*The JSFiddle example at the end*)

> Pay attention to the CSS `vertical` class selector

**CSS: ( *the essence of the change of carousel direction* )**

```
.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
   -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
   -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
   -ms-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
   -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
   transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
}

.carousel.vertical .active {
   top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .next {
   top: 400px;
}

.carousel.vertical .prev {
   top: -400px;
}

.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right {
   top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.left {
   top: -400px;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.right {
   top: 400px;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
   left: 0;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
   interval: 3000
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical">
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&amp;text=First+Slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&amp;text=Second+Slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&amp;text=Third+Slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/wram2h2p/

Comment: Is there any option where I can move the image in a curve(kind of half circle) top to bottom ?