# Transition between two slide (bootstrap carousel)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know how to have a better transition between my third and my first slide in CSS ?

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/D6MC948Gkc)

Answer (score 1):

From the **[latest answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30330303/2065039)** you might need to change your `CSS` as below and you need to add `vertical` class to `carousel-inner`. Check the **[Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/UJfuqm8Zvr)**

```
carousel-inner.vertical {
  height: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .item {
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
  -o-transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out top;
}
@media all and (transform-3d),
(-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active.right {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active.left {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner.vertical > .item.active {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .active {
  top: 0;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .next,
.carousel-inner.vertical > .prev {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .next {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .prev {
  left: 0;
  top: -100%
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .next.left,
.carousel-inner.vertical > .prev.right {
  top: 0;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .active.left {
  left: 0;
  top: -100%;
}
.carousel-inner.vertical > .active.right {
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like that the previous slide stay behind the new slide

Comment: Previous slide stay behind the new slide? You want them to hide instead of sliding up and slide up only those which comes active? like card stack?