# Bootstrap 3: Collapsing Panel - possibility to slide over the panel-heading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider

i faced a problem when i wanted to do some teaser-boxes with a fancy collapse-effect.

I'm sadly not a javascript/jQuery professional so i chose to ask here.

I have an OWL-Slider where i wanted to add some references with a Heading and a small picture.

Below the picture is text which describes the reference in a short sentence. Currently it slides above the picture/heading-box. I want to slide it on top of the picture so the website itself doesn't move. How can i archive this?

Is it actually possible with the built-in bootstrap mechanic or do i have to search for an alternative?

many thanks in advance and my booty-fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/91E7UkzcdI

Comment: so you want to make a gallary like where you can click on next and previous,is it what you saying?? Make yourself more clear and add some other websites example or anything else which helps to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: hello, i want to achieve that the current collapsing text just slides on top of the picture instead of sliding the picture down. currently it's the built-in bootstrap "collapse"-function, and i want to know how i can change that  its sliding the Picture and the Heading down instead of disappearing and the text fades or slides in at it's same place.

Comment: you lost me buddy,i am not so good with understanding things so i need live example to see what you exactly mean and there will be many examples online i am sure. Doesnt matter if its using bootstrap or not just find and example and add the link in question so it will become more clear

Comment: i'm very sorry. and you are probably right, with an example it would've been easier - but i didn't find one (maybe cause i don't really know how the effect is called) but after searching for like 3 hours today i found "jQuery Flip" - and thats like what i wanted: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/ but actually coded by myself and not with the flip-effect. it should've been with a sliding effect from top/bottom to bottom/top (both ways are ok). and i wanted to achieve that on my own or only with the help of bootstrap.

Comment: so in short you want a gallery slider with effect of sliding top to bottom or bottom to top.. An image gallery in which new image will appear from top to bottom or come in from bottom to top. right?

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589816/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-vertical-sliding) question and you might find your answer there