# Bootstrap Carousel slider sliding images horizontally not vertically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am working on bootstrap carousel slider i want to slide the images vertically but slider slides images horizontally.
Here is my code for Carousel i tried many attempts but the slider slides the images horizontally.

```
<div class=""> 


 <div class="">
                            <div id="myCarousel" class="vertical-slider carousel vertical slide col-md-12" data-ride="carousel">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <span data-slide="next" class="btn-vertical-slider glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up "
                                              style="font-size: 30px"> </span>  
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8"> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />

                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="item" id="side_slider_rep">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <a id='side_slide_iss_href' href="javascript:void(0);"> <img src="images/img_pre.jpg" class="img-responsive" id='side_slide_img' /> </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <h4><a id='side_slide_iss_href' href="javascript:void(0);"><span id='side_slide_iss_book_name'></span><span id='side_slide_iss_name'></span></a>
                                                </h4>
                                                <!--                                            <p id='side_slide_iss_desc'> Years back, there was a real divide between DC and Marvel. DC was the stoic old guard</p>-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="side_slider_rep_end" style ="display: none;"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <span data-slide="prev" class="btn-vertical-slider glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"
                                              style="color: Black; font-size: 30px"> </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I have posted my code as well

Comment: Here is your solution: [Bootstrap-carousel-vertical-sliding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589816/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-vertical-sliding)

Comment: Thanks Münich it solves my problem