# Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 Vertical Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to create a vertically oriented carousel in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6. I still can't figure out for the life of me why the folks at Bootstrap don't include this orientation but I've come close to a solution of my own. I seem to be missing something in my CSS but cant seem to place it.

Check out my demo here on **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/jcvd3u0r/)**

My problem is the non upward fluid movement of the carousel slides. The slides come up from the bottom but don't continue up  when they're ending -- dissappear rather.

I'm building this code from compiling old methods of doing this with BS3 and trying to match up the new CSS classes the best I can. Here's my code, any help in solving this mystery would be much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Bootstrap Carousel -->
<div id="testCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#testCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#testCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#testCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/2500x750" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/2500x750" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/2500x750" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Just for Example Purposes */
body {
  background: #333
}

/* Vertical Carousel */

.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
     -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
      -ms-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
       -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
          transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
}

.carousel.vertical .active {
   top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-item-next {
   top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-item-prev {
   top: -100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
   top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.carousel-item-left {
   top: -100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.carousel-item-right {
   top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-item {
  left: 0;
}
```

So, rather than the carousel slides blinking out or just disappearing, then reappearing, I would like them to flow naturally upward as if the hidden images weren't left aligned as they are by default in Bootstrap.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Updated 2018 for Bootstrap 4.0.0***

The **Bootstrap** 4 animation transitions use `transform`, so I think it would be better to use `translate` to change the orientation to vertical, and the position of each slide...

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/PgxKT3h6x6

```
.vert .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.vert .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.vert .carousel-item-next,
.vert .active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 100% 0);
}

.vert .carousel-item-prev,
.vert .active.carousel-item-left {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0,-100%, 0);
}
```

[Vertical Carousel Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/PgxKT3h6x6/bootstrap-4-vertical-slider)