# Bootstrap Carousel Made Vertical

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrapper

Im looking to change my bootstrap carousel to vertical rotation. Currently i have the carousel in html, the image sizing in css and the navigation left and right assigned to mouse scrolling in JS with the left right buttons disabled in visual studio.

Ive tried a whole different mix of fixtures online and non of it has worked.

```
    <div id="carouselScrolling" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!--Lower Indicators-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!--Slides-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url(/images/carousel1.jpg);">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
                    <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(/images/carousel2.jpg)">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
                    <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
            <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(/images/carousel3.jpg)">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
                    <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Next Prev Buttons-->
        @*<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>*@

    </div>
```

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 350px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```
$('#carouselScrolling').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
        $(this).carousel('prev');
    } else {
        $(this).carousel('next');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/2zosm3s6/)** from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589816/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-vertical-sliding

Comment: Ive looked at that before and it dident work but ive managed to understand how it works a bit more so ill check again but so far no luck